# How to be parameterized that 2 projects which is "Build after other projects are built"

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have a problem and I'm looking for a direct solution or a
workaround.

I have 2 jobs on Jenkins: job A (the upstream job) and job B (the downstream
job) that needs to be triggered after job A has finished

I used to solve this problem with: "This project is parameterized" set on job A,B and it worked perfectly fine. but on job B it does not work. When I build with parameter job A, jenkins wants a parameter for job A and then triggering Job B. job B needs a new parameter. Jenkins does not want new parameter for job B.  I need to give paramateres both projects. Is there any solution ?

Comment: So you have a parameter in JOB A but the same parameter is not passing down to the JOB B?

Comment: Job A has a parameters. Job B has also parameters. When I Click > build with parameters > i wrote job a's parameters > triggering job b > job b was built

But i need give paramaters for job b

Comment: Maybe I need to pass parameters down project that is job B

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you need to pass `PARAM1` and `PARAM2` to `JOB B`.

Declare `PARAM1` and `PARAM2` in `JOB A`, then pass both the parameters to `JOB B` in the post build action in `Trigger Parameterized Job` like this:

`param1 = $PARAM1`

`param2 = $PARAM2`

Then in `JOB B` declare `param1` and `param2`.

This should do the trick.